# Why doesn't servlet update the parameter?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Servlet receives request when the button is clicked. The servlet sets foo parameter to a random number x. `System.out.println(x)` produces different value at every request. However, on the client side, `console.log(${foo})` always prints the first number that was generated. What is going on?

Servlet:

```
public class First extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        double x = Math.random();
        req.getSession().setAttribute("foo", x);
        System.out.println(x);
        RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        rd.forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
        <c:out value = "${foo}"/>
        <script>
            $(document).on("click", "#button", function() { 
                $.get("first", function(responseText) {  
                 console.log(${foo});
                });
            });
        </script>
        <input type="submit" id="button">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it still display the first value when you refresh the page? `${foo}` is probably loaded every page refresh, not every button click  (the button click just shows the already loaded value)

Comment: After the first refresh it displays a new number, but on the second and on it stays that number

Comment: Is there a way to refresh it on click?

Comment: The `${foo}` is only replaced on the server-side NOT the client side with java script. Either fix your javascript to update the value or don't use javascript and use a regular request/response.

Comment: How is it possible to update this value with javascript?